# Guess a number program with Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to create a program in Java in which the computer randomly guesses a number between 1-100 and allows the user to guess to the number.

If the number is lower than the random number the program should say: `lower!` and if higher, the program should say: `higher!`

If the user guesses the right number, it should say `congratulations you guessed the right number in X amount of tries`.

This is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionOne
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
   int guess;

   System.out.println("I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100 ... guess what it is ?");
   guess = keyboard.nextInt();

   while(guess != a){
   if (guess > a)
   {  
     System.out.println("lower!");

   }
   else if (guess < a) 
   {
    System.out.println("higher!");

   }
   else 
   {
     System.out.println("Congratulations.   You guessed the number with X tries!");
   }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your question ? Are you running an infinite loop ?

Comment: You explain what you are trying to do and all, but you never actually say what you need help with. Are you having a problem? Or are you just being lazy and don't want to finish it?

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to move the code that inputs the number into the loop

Comment: oh sorry well im just having trouble with the end where it says congratulations. You guessed the number with X tries. I am not sure how to count how many times the loop was repeated. @BobbyD17

Comment: I am not sure how to count the the loop for the end part where it says congratulations, you guessed in X tries. I am not sure how to determine X @ZouZou

Comment: add a counter variable outside of the loop and increment it during each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't getting another input, or keeping count. Try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
    int guess = 0;

    System.out.println("I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100"
        + " ... guess what it is ?");

    while (guess != a) {
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        count++;
        if (guess > a) {
            System.out.println("lower!");
        } else if (guess < a) {
            System.out.println("higher!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number with "
        + count + " tries!");
}
```

Output

```
I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100 ... guess what it is ? 
50
higher!
75
lower!
62
Congratulations.   You guessed the number with 3 tries!
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to get a new int from the scanner in each loop :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionOne
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99),
       guess, 
       count = 0;

   System.out.println("I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100 ... guess what it is ?");

   while((guess = keyboard.nextInt()) != a){
     if (guess > a)
     {  
       System.out.println("lower!");
     }
     else
     {
       System.out.println("higher!");
     }
     count++;
   }

   System.out.println("Congratulations.   You guessed the number with "+ count +" tries!");
  }

}
```

**edit :** I'm currently bored... Add the counter ;)

Comment: You could just put an `else` instead of `else if (guess < a) `

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it will help.

`public class BinarySearch`

```
{ static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String a[]) {
    int count = 100;
    BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch();
    int[] inputArr = bs.takeInputsInCount(count);
    System.out
            .println("For every question, press Enter if answer is YES, else you can press any other key");
    System.out
            .println("Think of a number between 1 to 100, press Enter to continue");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        int element = bs.getElementByBinarySearch(inputArr, count);
        System.out.println("Your number is : " + element);
    } else {
        System.out.println("exiting... ");

    }
}

private int getElementByBinarySearch(int[] arr, int len) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = len - 1;
    if (isEqual(arr[first]))
        return arr[first];
    if (isEqual(arr[last]))
        return arr[last];
    while (last > first) {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;

        if (isEqual(arr[middle]))
            return arr[middle];
        if (isGreater(arr[middle])) {
            first = middle + 1;
            if (isEqual(arr[first]))
                return arr[first];
        } else {
            last = middle - 1;
            if (isEqual(arr[last]))
                return arr[last];
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

private boolean isEqual(int m) {
    Boolean equalFlag = false;

    System.out.println("Is your number :" + m + " ?");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        equalFlag = true;
    }
    return equalFlag;

}

private boolean isGreater(int m) {
    Boolean equalFlag = false;

    System.out.println("Is your number greater than :" + m + " ? ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        equalFlag = true;
    }
    return equalFlag;

}

private int[] takeInputsInCount(int count) {
    int length = count;
    int tempArray[] = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        try {
            tempArray[i] = i + 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return tempArray;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the congratulations part out of the while loop. If you guess the correct number, it will not go into the loop and therefore will not ever display that statement. This would be more obvious if you fixed your indentations. Its bad form to have everything at the same indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

Well I crossed across this topic and would like to share the code I figured out too since it was a fun question.This can even be used as a simple game.below is the psuedocode for it :D

```
do{
        number=(int)(Math.random()*100);

   }while(number<10);
do
    {
  lottery=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"guess the two digit number which is in my mind!!!! \nenter the number"));
  if(number<lottery)
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"guess a more lower number");
      count ++;
   }
  else if(number>lottery)
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"guess a more higher number");
      count ++;
     }
  else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you have guessed the correct number "+number+" in"+count+" tries");
    }while(lottery!=number);</i>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Random;

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int a = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*99);
    int guess = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(guess != a)
    {
        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number"));
        count++;
        if (guess > a)
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"lower!");
        }
       else if (guess < a)
        {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"higher!");
        }
    }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Congratulations. You guessed the number with " +count+ " tries");
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you aware that this question was asked more than year a go? also you answer don't differ to much from other answers, please read what a goo [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is.