# Having the user guess a random number and loop until they get it right

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure this out for hours but I can't for some reason my output just shows "Sorry that number is too high" and "Sorry that number is too low" at the same time without looping or using a single answer.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random numGen = new Random();
        int RanNum = numGen.nextInt(20) + 1; 
        System.out.println("Guess what number im thinking of");
        int num ;
        num = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (num == RanNum)
            System.out.println("Good Job");
        else if  (num > RanNum)
            System.out.println("Sorry that number is too high");
        else if (num < RanNum);
        System.out.println("Sorry that number is too low");

    }
}
```

Comment: The code indentation is actually correctly showing that last `println` statement is **not** covered by the `else if` statement, because you have a `;` at the end of that line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guess a number program with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048870/guess-a-number-program-with-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semicolon after `else if (num < RanNum)` is your problem

Comment: Hi i have another question ive been trying to loop this program so that it asks the user again after telling them there answer is too high or too low and im having no success is there any chance you could throw some advice my way

Answer (score 0):

you misplaced a semicolon at the end of your third if.
You should still get the Good Job message though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random numGen = new Random();
    int RanNum = numGen.nextInt(1) + 1; 
    System.out.println("Guess what number im thinking of");
    int num ;
    num = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (num == RanNum)
        System.out.println("Good Job");
    else if  (num > RanNum)
        System.out.println("Sorry that number is too high");
    else if (num < RanNum)
        System.out.println("Sorry that number is too low");

}
```

edit: sorry, too late :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep prompting the user use a while loop to check whether they guessed correct or not. I would also recommend adding another input check for exiting without getting it correct. Brief example:

```
boolean incorrect = true;
while(incorrect) {

  //Code to prompt for input

  if(userIsCorrect || input == -1){
    incorrect = false;
    //Program will exit loop when this is set to false
  }
}
```